# How can I set my current location for geolocation APIs to pick up?

Tags: windows-7, geolocation

I'm running a Windows 7 desktop machine (no GPS, hardwired connection) which is stationary. I'd like to set up my location so that various geolocation-enabled services can find me accurately. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A good example is my browser (Firefox) via the geolocation APIs added to HTML 5.

Comment: That is up to the browser then. FireFox would need to provide support for HTML 5 and thus the geolocation behavior available in HTML 5. It would be browser specific; perhaps providing the ability to provide a default location within a browser settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 needs a sensor installed to provide the services (Google) with information pertinent to the service.

One such sensor is [Geosense](http://geosenseforwindows.com/) which will provide the behavior you are looking for. The sensor currently supports Google Location Services via IP/WiFi.

The framework exists within Windows 7 but it still requires 3rd party implementations which will provide the sensors and thus integration to services such as Bing/Google. Unfortunately; the developer community has been fairly slow to respond thus far.

With regard to geolocation via HTML 5; that is reliant on the browser and how they support HTML 5 and consequently geolocation. If you encountered a page written in HTML 5 leveraging the geolocation API's; the browser implementation would come into realization at that point. If the browser provided a way via browser settings to provide a fixed latitude/longitude position, that would be up to the specific browser in use.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was some application/driver that could pretend to be a sensor and just allow me to set my lat/long manually. My desktop doesn't have Wifi and the IP address lookup puts me 30 miles away so most of the normal methods don't work.

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of; as everything generally leverages WiFi/IP or actual GPS coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately, Geosense has been discontinued and you cannot download the software from their website. They recommend upgrading to Windows 8.