# What determines the current browser location on desktop PC and how can it be changed?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, geolocation

When Google Chrome asks me to share my location with a website that uses the geolocation feature such as [mycurrentlocation.net](https://mycurrentlocation.net/), and I allow it, the website locates me a few kilometers away in the next big town and shows a low accuracy value.

My stationary desktop PC doesn't have GPS or WiFI or GSM, so I guess the information comes from my IP address.

That begs the questions:

1. Why does the browser even ask for approval to share that
   information, because my IP is shared with the website anyway? How
   does it matter whether I click Allow or Deny?
2. How can I tell my browser
   or the OS a more exact location? Some location services are actually
   useful, such as when I'm ordering a pizza or search through
   classified ads.

Things I tried:

- Google Chrome -> Developer tools -> Sensors -> Specify exact location

  (is not kept across browser sessions)
- Windows -> Settings -> Change default location

  (doesn't seem to have an effect on Google Chrome's geolocation feature)

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, IP address (resolved by GeoIP databases), local WIFI networks and other things can be used to provide rough location data.

Comment: @Mokubai - the duplicate doesn't answer the second question here though *"How can I tell my browser or the OS a more exact location? "*.  Perhaps a duplicate of [Is it possible to provide local geolocation data?](https://superuser.com/a/733567/269373)

Comment: How about [How can I set my current location for geolocation APIs to pick up?](https://superuser.com/questions/260872/how-can-i-set-my-current-location-for-geolocation-apis-to-pick-up?rq=1)

Comment: @Mokubai In the end, none of the specific questions I asked are answered in any of the linked "duplicates", and all given unspecific recommendations I have also already listed in "things I tried" with reason why they are not useful here. I've read all these "duplicates" before opening my question. :(